# Change NSDate format

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an NSDate object with format "yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00 " and I want to change this NSDate into the format "dd/MM/yyyy". I have found a lot of examples changing format from strings to NSDate using NSDateformater, but not if you have a NSDate and need to change it.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "NSDate format" - NSDate stores a date as an object - it is only represented as a string when you use an NSDateFormatter. Perhaps if you explain what you are trying to achieve that would help.

Comment: Your date cant have a format `yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00 ` NSDate must have timestamp and timezone with it.

Comment: You can't change the format of an NSDate.  The format printed by `description` is for diagnostic purposes only.  You must *format* the date into an NSString using NSDateFormatter.

Comment: More accurately, NSDate stores "an instant in time" - independent of time zones, calendars or the current rotational position of the Earth.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSString *resultString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[formatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this one**

```
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSString *dateStr = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: What do you mean by blind.And you know its my own opinion.So please don't use this word in future for anyone.

Comment: @Dharmbir, ignore him. Your answer is right, vote Up for you.